# How do I remove text before a specific word and numbers greater than from all lines, then remove duplicates?

Tags: powershell

I have a large txt file and need to remove irrelevant text and numbers greater than or within a range.

I have the following example txt file:

```txt
2022-09-27 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 1
2022-09-27 00:10:01 All bus routes Local route 2
2022-09-27 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 16
2022-09-27 15:00:01 All bus routes Local route 58
2022-10-07 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 1
2022-10-17 00:10:01 All bus routes Local route 2
2022-09-27 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 16
2022-09-27 15:00:01 All bus routes Local route 99
2022-11-14 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 1
2022-09-27 00:10:01 All bus routes Local route 2
2022-09-27 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 16
2022-09-27 15:00:01 All bus routes Local route 62248
2022-09-27 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 1
2022-09-27 00:10:01 All bus routes Local route 222
2022-09-27 00:00:01 All bus routes Local route 16
2022-09-27 15:00:01 All bus routes Local route 58
```

What I am trying to do is remove all text before the word Local and all routes greater than 90.

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\Buses.txt
-replace "Local [-1]", ""   
-replace "90 [+1]", ""
Set-Content C:\Temp\Buses1.txt
```

The above obviously does not work, what am I doing wrong?

The aim is to also remove duplicate lines and those that are not applicable to the results.

Comment: I have also tried this:
    Get-Content C:\Temp\Test.txt |
    Foreach {$_.replace("*Local","")}|   
    Set-Content C:\Temp\Test1.txt

Comment: You better select what you need (rather than what you don't need): `$Bus |Select-String -AllMatches 'Local route \d\d?\b' | foreach-object {$_.Matches.Value}` (up to bus 99)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses regex to only keep the text 'Local route xx' and filter out routes >90:

```
$Routes = Foreach ($line in (Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Buses.txt')) {
  if ($line -match 'Local route (\d{1,2})$') {  ## only one or two-digit routes
    if ($matches[1] -lt 90) {  ## only routes <90
      $matches[0]  ## output matched text
    }
  }
}
# view output with no duplicates
$Routes | Select -Unique

Local route 1
Local route 2
Local route 16
Local route 58  ## etc...


# Save to file with:
$Routes | Select -Unique | Set-Content 'C:\Temp\Buses1.txt'
```